# Mapping a table with a compound primary key to a python dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, composite-primary-key

I've got some data which originally looks like this which I'd like to process in Python 2.7:

```
id  year    value
1   2012    5
2   2012    50
3   2012    500
1   2013    6
2   2013    60
3   2013    600
1   2014    7
2   2014    70
3   2014    700
```

I can easily transform it into a list like this `[[1,2012,5],[2,2012,6],...]`.

I'd like to convert this to a dictionary, as I'd like to look up all different values for a fixed `id` and/or `year` (If this idea is not so great and I should rather keep it as a list, please let me know in the comments.)

I know that a python dictionary needs a hashable key, so I could transform this table by concatenating `id` and `year` to a string and have a dictionary like

```
{'1_2012':'5','2_2012':'50', ...}
```

Obviously, this is not very elegant if you want to read out the separate parts of the key. What's the easiest way to get a compound key dictionary which is still easily `dump`able into a json?

Comment: If you want to look up in different ways, it sounds like you need *multiple* structures. Note that dictionary keys can be tuples, so e.g. `{(1, 2012): 5, ...}` would be valid; however, I don't know if JSON will handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tuple` is hashable:

```
{(1, 2012): 5, (2, 2012): 50,}
```

However, this dict cannot be `dump`ed, the dict key in this case should be a string:

```
import json
import ast

# Works if keys satisfy following requirement:
# key == ast.literal_eval(repr(key))
# This is true for tuples having numbers inside.

def dumps(d):
    return json.dumps({repr(key): value for key, value in d.items()})

def loads(s):
    d = json.loads(s)
    return {ast.literal_eval(key): value for key, value in d.items()}
```

This pair of function should go until you start using keys that are complex enough and/or that have their `__repr__` method implemented poorly.

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet, but this seems like the best idea. I haven't decided if I want to use `tuple` or `namedtuple` as key. The latter is also hashable, right? Do you know if this already touches an area of poor `__repr__` and/or too complex keys?

Comment: @Roland `__repr__` of a `namedtuple` is enough to satisfy `key == ast.literal_eval(repr(key))`  - while both sender and receiver of the `json` string have the same definition of the `namedtuple` in their scope. This makes namedtuples not so different from just tuples, so I would go with the latter. Tuples occupy less space in RAM and `json`, and probably they work faster. However, if you have a lot of such data structures to send over multiple places, `namedtuple` should be picked, as `explicit is better than implicit`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tuples as keys.  You can create a tuple using parentheses, e.g. `(2,2012)` is a tuple.  They are immutable, and so can be used as dict keys:

```
d = {(1,2012):5, (2,2012):50}
```

You can index into tuples just as you index into a list, e.g. `(1,2012)[1]` is `2012`.

Comment: How do you dump such a dictionary into json?

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose I would suggest using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) as it's clearer than a standard tuple.

```
import collections
Key = collections.namedtuple('Key', ['id', 'year'])
data = {Key(id=1, year=2012): 5, Key(id=2, year=2012): 50}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `namedtuple`s are not very easy to `dump` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906831/serializing-a-python-namedtuple-to-json)

Comment: It takes a little bit of extra effort, but with a predefined format like this it's fairly easy to do.