# Why is python's json.loads/dumps roundtrip lossy?

Tags: python, json, serialization

I'm using python to serialize a python object to store it in my cache. For this serialization, I'm using `json.dumps()` and to unserialize it after I get it out of the cache, I'm using `json.loads()`. I assumed this roundtrip would work without any trouble. But as you can see below it fails.

```
>>> import json
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> x = {"hello": 1, "goodbye": 2}
>>> y = namedtuple('Struct', x.keys())(*x.values())
>>> y
Struct(goodbye=2, hello=1)

>>> json.loads(json.dumps(y))
[2, 1]           # <= I expected this to be the same value as y above!!
```

Why is this json.dumps/loads roundtrip lossy? What function can I use to serialize this object to that unserialization will preserve its original value? I tried to use `pickle` but it fails to serialize the object.

Comment: json doesn't know about namedtuples.

Comment: JSON is not meant to deal with arbitrary user-defined object types. JSON supports "json objects" which correspond to Python `dict`, and "JSON arrays", which corresponds to Python `list`. Apparently, the python `json` module assumes that if you pass it a `tuple`, it gets serialized as a JSON array. But this will always be deserialized as a Python list. You can use `pickle` to serialize types returned by `namedtuple`, but you have to keep the type around. You create the type, instantiate the type, and throw away the type in one swoop: `namedtuple('Struct', x.keys())(*x.values())`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why not making an answer out of this long comment?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate somewhere, and I was looking for it, but still haven't found it. I may be misremembering things. I think your answer is fine, I would undelete it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I found a similar Q&A but it's not a duplicate because it doesn't _explain_ why the field names are lost.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga, Ok. I want to use `pickle` as you suggested. Can you show   me how to keep the type around such that it can be used by `pickle.dumps()`? Or is there a way I can define the serializer when I create the namedtuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json` tries to serialize the object according to its type. It cannot serialize any object but only the "basic" ones, such as `tuple` (converting to square brackets like `list`), `dict`, `list` ... (and of course integers, strings, floats).

When testing your object using `isinstance`, it succeeds on `tuple` because `namedtuple` is designed to inherit from `tuple`:

```
y = namedtuple('Struct', x.keys())(*x.values())
print(isinstance(y,tuple))
```

result is `True`.

So in the `encoder.py` file in `json` module, your data is matching the `isinstance` test in `iterencode` method (code extract below, around line 311 for my Python 3.4 version):

```
   if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
        chunks = _iterencode_list(value, _current_indent_level)
```

So any type inheriting from `list` or `tuple` is serialized like a `list`

A workaround for that is proposed here: [Serializing a Python namedtuple to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906831/serializing-a-python-namedtuple-to-json)