# Why doesn't JSONEncoder work for namedtuples?

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I am unable to to dump `collections.namedtuple` as correct JSON.

***First***, consider the [official](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#module-json) example for using custom JSON serializer:

```
import json

class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, complex):
            return [obj.real, obj.imag]
        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

json.dumps(2 + 1j, cls=ComplexEncoder)   # works great, without a doubt
```

***Second***, now consider the following example which tells Python how to JSONize a `Friend` object:

```
import json

class Friend():
    """ struct-like, for storing state details of a friend """
    def __init__(self, _id, f_name, l_name):
        self._id = _id
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name

t = Friend(21, 'Steve', 'Rogerson')

class FriendEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """ take a Friend object and make it truly json """
    def default(self, aFriend):
        if isinstance(aFriend, Friend):
            return {
                "id": aFriend._id,
                "f_name": aFriend.f_name,
                "l_name": aFriend.l_name,
            }
        return super(FriendEncoder, self).default(aFriend)

json.dumps(t, cls=FriendEncoder) # returns correctly JSONized string
```

***Finally*** when we try to implement the same thing using namedtuples, `json.dumps(t, cls=FriendEncoder)` doesn't give any errors but gives the wrong output. Take a look:

```
import pdb
import json
from collections import namedtuple

Friend = namedtuple("Friend", ["id", 'f_name', 'l_name'])

t = Friend(21, 'Steve', 'Rogerson')

print(t)

class FriendEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """ take a Friend collections.namedtuple object and make it truly json """
    def default(self, obj):
        if True:    # if isinstance(obj, Friend):
            ans = dict(obj._asdict())
            pdb.set_trace()     # WOW!! even after commenting out the if and hardcoding True, debugger doesn't get called
            return ans
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

json.dumps(t, cls=FriendEncoder)
```

The output I get is not a dict-like but rather just a list of values i.e. `[21, 'Steve', 'Rogerson']`

#### Why?

Is the default behavior such that information is lost?
Does json.dumps ignore the explicitly passed encoder?

---

**Edit:** by correctly jsonized namedtuple I mean that json.dumps should return data like *exactly* `dict(nt._asdict())`, where `nt` is a pre defined namedtuple

Comment: The `default` method doesn't get called for subclasses of `tuple`, `list` etc.

Comment: @vaultah I agree that `default` method isn't getting called. But can you substantiate "for subclasses of `tuple`, `list`, etc."

Comment: The `json.JSONEncoder` only calls `default ()` on objects it doesn't already know how serialize itself, which includes `tuple`s, `list`s and `dict`s (and subclasses of them). This means that in order to do what you want, you'll need to "trick" it.

Comment: Please describe you what think/want a `namedtuple` that has been "truly" converted to JSON would look like since such as thing is not a defined [JSON object](http://json.org/) Also, how do you expect it to be decoded later if it's non-standard?

Comment: "`json.JSONEncoder` only calls `default ()` on objects it doesn't already know how serialize itself, which includes `tuples`, `lists` and ..." I can't understand the underlying source code (`json/encoder.py`) can you please explain?

Comment: The `__repr__` of an object is just a string, which is also one of the thing sthe `json.JSONEncoder` already knows how to encode. The [**Encoders and Decoders**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) section of the `json` documentation has a list of them. I soon will post an answer that shows one way to get around this for specific types, like `namedtuple`s.

Answer (score 9):

As I said in a comment, the `json.JSONEncoder` only calls `default` when it encounters an object type it doesn't already know how to serialize itself. There's a [table of them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table) in the `json` documentation. Here's a screenshot of it for easy reference:

[image: table of types supported by default]

Note that `tuple` is on the list, and since `namedtuple` is a subclasses of `tuple`, it applies to them, too. (i.e. because `isinstance(friend_instance, tuple)` → `True`).

**This is why your code for handling instances of the `Friend` class never gets called.**

Below is one workaround — namely by creating a simple `Wrapper` class whose instances *won't* be a type that the `json.JSONEncoder` thinks it already knows how to handle, and then specifying a `default=` keyword argument function that's to be called whenever an object is encountered that it doesn't already know how to do.

Here's what I mean:

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

class Wrapper(object):
    """ Container class for objects with an _asdict() method. """
    def __init__(self, obj):
        assert hasattr(obj, '_asdict'), 'Cannot wrap object with no _asdict method'
        self.obj = obj


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Friend = namedtuple("Friend", ["id", 'f_name', 'l_name'])
    t = Friend(21, 'Steve', 'Rogerson')
    print(t)
    print(json.dumps(t))
    print(json.dumps(Wrapper(t), default=lambda wrapped: wrapped.obj._asdict()))
```

Output:

```
Friend(id=21, f_name='Steve', l_name='Rogerson')
[21, "Steve", "Rogerson"]
{"id": 21, "f_name": "Steve", "l_name": "Rogerson"}
```

For some additional information and insights, also check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18561055/355230) to the related question [Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder).

Comment: I am looking for solution on similar question. Thank you very much.